# Contact form doesnt send email, Error page

Tags: html, forms, contacts

Hi I really need help with this.

I have just finished a design for a client and her website went live on Thursday, however the contact form doesn't work. I do know things about HTML/CSS but I am very basic with stuff with script. When you fill in the form and press send a 'not found' page appears.

Whats gone wrong?

I have tried looking at other posts about this kind of thing but I think the code needs looking at.

Much appreciated

//email form validation

function everif(str) {

```
    var at="@"
    var punct="."
    var lat=str.indexOf(at)
    var lstr=str.length
    var lpunct=str.indexOf(punct)
    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1){
       alert("Valid email must be entered")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(at)==-1 || str.indexOf(at)==0 || str.indexOf(at)==lstr){
       alert("Valid email must be entered")
       return false
    }

    if (str.indexOf(punct)==-1 || str.indexOf(punct)==0 || str.indexOf(punct)==lstr){
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
    }

     if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
     }

     if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==punct || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==punct){
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(punct,(lat+2))==-1){
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
     }

     if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
        alert("Valid email must be entered")
        return false
     }

     return true                    
}
```

function evalid(){
    var emailID=document.contact_form.mail

```
if (everif(emailID.value)==false){
    emailID.focus()
    return false
}
```

//empty field validation

```
var fname=document.contact_form.fname
if ((fname.value==null)||(fname.value=="")){
    alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
    fname.focus()
    return false
    }

var lname=document.contact_form.lname       
if ((lname.value==null)||(lname.value=="")){
    alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
    lname.focus()
    return false
    }

var message=document.contact_form.message   
if ((message.value==null)||(message.value=="")){
    alert("Fields marqued with * must be entered")
    message.focus()
    return false
    }

return true
```

}

```
 </script>
 <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="mailer.php" onSubmit="return evalid()">
 <table border="0"><tr>

  <td colspan="2"><input name="fname" type="text" value="First Name" size="40" /></td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input name="lname" type="text" value="Last Name" size="40" /></td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" value="Email" name="mail" size="40" /></td>
   </tr><tr>
  <td colspan="2"><textarea name="message" value="Your Message" onkeyup="return limitarelungime(this, 255)"  cols="35" rows="5"></textarea></td>
   </tr><tr>
   <td></td>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
   <td align="right">
   <input type="image" src="images/send.png" value="Submit" alt="submit" name="submit"/>
     </td>
    <td align="right"><alt="Valid Contact Form" width="20" height="20" border="0" /></a></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     </form>    
     </div>
```

Comment: Does your server actually contain the file `mailer.php`?

Answer (score 0):

**Page not found error** suggests that there is some problem with the URL redirect quite simply or the file does not exist. In your case if the form is sending the data to a *mailer.php* script, just make sure that the path of the file is entered correctly and that the file is there in a particular folder according to the path. Your problem should be solved.

Comment: I don't think there is a mailer.php in the file, that must be the problem. Will sort that out as soon as I can. Thank you very much